# Apt-get update runs without errors but doesn't really update package list

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, update-manager

I installed 14.10 64 bits, three weeks ago, I never got any package to update.
When I do `apt-get update`, I won't get any error, but updating of the package list is very fast and downloaded sizes seems very small, so i think it's not updating anything.

When doing `apt-get upgrade`, it never find anything.

Here is the output of `apt-get update`, in French but I guess you will figure it out.

```
vincent@vincent-LIFEBOOK-E554:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for vincent: 
Ign http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic InRelease
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security InRelease                       
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic InRelease                                  
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic InRelease                                  
Ign http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates InRelease                      
Atteint http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security Release.gpg                 
Atteint http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic InRelease                                  
Atteint http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic Release.gpg                            
Ign http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports InRelease                    
Atteint http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security Release                     
Atteint http://dl.google.com stable Release                                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic InRelease                                  
Atteint http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic Release                                
Atteint http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic Release.gpg                        
Atteint http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/main Sources                
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic InRelease                                  
Atteint http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic/main Sources                           
Atteint http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates Release.gpg                
Atteint http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                        
Atteint http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release.gpg                            
Atteint http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/restricted Sources          
Atteint http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic/main amd64 Packages                    
Réception de : 1 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports Release.gpg [933 B]
Atteint http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                         
Ign http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org dist InRelease                         
Atteint http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release.gpg                            
Atteint http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/universe Sources            
Atteint http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic/main i386 Packages                     
Atteint http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic Release                            
Atteint http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release.gpg                            
Atteint http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/multiverse Sources          
Atteint http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates Release                    
Atteint http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release.gpg                            
Atteint http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/main amd64 Packages         
Réception de : 2 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports Release [62,0 kB]
Atteint http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                         
Atteint http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release                                
Atteint http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/restricted amd64 Packages   
Atteint http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free amd64 Packages           
Atteint http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release                                
Atteint http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/universe amd64 Packages     
Atteint http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free i386 Packages            
Atteint http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release                                
Atteint http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/multiverse amd64 Packages   
Atteint http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release                                
Atteint http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/main i386 Packages          
Atteint http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org dist Release.gpg                   
Atteint http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/main Sources                       
Atteint http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main amd64 Packages                    
Atteint http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/restricted i386 Packages    
Atteint http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/restricted Sources                 
Atteint http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main i386 Packages                     
Atteint http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/universe i386 Packages      
Atteint http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/universe Sources                   
Atteint http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main Translation-en                    
Atteint http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/multiverse i386 Packages    
Atteint http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/multiverse Sources                 
Atteint http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main amd64 Packages                    
Atteint http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/main Translation-en         
Atteint http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/main amd64 Packages                
Atteint http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main i386 Packages                     
Atteint http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/multiverse Translation-en   
Atteint http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/restricted amd64 Packages          
Atteint http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main Translation-en                    
Atteint http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/universe amd64 Packages            
Atteint http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/restricted Translation-en   
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic/main Translation-fr_FR                     
Atteint http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org dist Release                       
Atteint http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/multiverse amd64 Packages          
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic/main Translation-fr                        
Atteint http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main amd64 Packages                    
Atteint http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/main i386 Packages                 
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic/main Translation-en                        
Atteint http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main i386 Packages                     
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-fr_FR                         
Atteint http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/restricted i386 Packages           
Atteint http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main Translation-en                    
Atteint http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/universe Translation-en     
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-fr                            
Atteint http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main amd64 Packages                    
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Ign http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free Translation-fr_FR            
Atteint http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main i386 Packages                     
Atteint http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/universe i386 Packages             
Ign http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free Translation-fr               
Atteint http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org dist/10gen amd64 Packages          
Atteint http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/multiverse i386 Packages           
Ign http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free Translation-en               
Atteint http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/main Translation-fr                
Atteint http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/main Translation-en                
Atteint http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/multiverse Translation-fr          
Atteint http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/multiverse Translation-en          
Atteint http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/restricted Translation-fr          
Atteint http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/restricted Translation-en          
Atteint http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org dist/10gen i386 Packages           
Atteint http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/universe Translation-fr            
Atteint http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/universe Translation-en            
Atteint http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/main Sources               
Atteint http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/restricted Sources         
Atteint http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/universe Sources           
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main Translation-fr_FR                     
Atteint http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/multiverse Sources         
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main Translation-fr                        
Atteint http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/main amd64 Packages        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main Translation-en                        
Atteint http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/restricted amd64 Packages  
Atteint http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/universe amd64 Packages    
Atteint http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages  
Atteint http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/main i386 Packages         
Atteint http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/restricted i386 Packages   
Atteint http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/universe i386 Packages     
Atteint http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/multiverse i386 Packages   
Atteint http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/main Translation-en        
Atteint http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/multiverse Translation-en  
Atteint http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/restricted Translation-en  
Atteint http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/universe Translation-en    
Réception de : 3 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/main Sources [751 B]
Réception de : 4 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/restricted Sources [14 B]
Réception de : 5 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/universe Sources [6 557 B]
Réception de : 6 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/multiverse Sources [14 B]
Réception de : 7 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/main amd64 Packages [556 B]
Réception de : 8 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/restricted amd64 Packages [14 B]
Réception de : 9 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/universe amd64 Packages [5 549 B]
Réception de : 10 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages [14 B]
Réception de : 11 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/main i386 Packages [560 B]
Réception de : 12 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/restricted i386 Packages [14 B]
Réception de : 13 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/universe i386 Packages [5 546 B]
Réception de : 14 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/multiverse i386 Packages [14 B]
Atteint http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/main Translation-en      
Atteint http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Atteint http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/restricted Translation-en
Atteint http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/universe Translation-en  
Ign http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org dist/10gen Translation-fr_FR           
Ign http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org dist/10gen Translation-fr
Ign http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org dist/10gen Translation-en
82,5 ko réceptionnés en 5s (14,1 ko/s)
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
vincent@vincent-LIFEBOOK-E554:~$
```

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

Check which package is having conflict while installing by using the below command,

```
apt-mark showhold
```

After doing so unhold by using the below command,

```
sudo apt-mark unhold <package name>
```

Once you are done with the above remove the conflict package and install it again. Hope this will help.

Comment: Why do you think there is a conflict ?
apt-mark showhold gives no answer at all.

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue here on Ubuntu 14.10 (upgraded from an original install of 14.04). Looking at the history logs for apt, the last time any official package was upgraded was december 22nd 2014, when I manually ran an apt-get upgrade. On december 30th, I ran an apt-get upgrade before installing bumblebee, and the only package that got updated was google-chrome-stable (from the google repository). Installation of new packages still works.

According to dpkg, I have a 3.16 kernel installed:

```
# dpkg-query -l linux-headers-generic
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                        Version                    Architecture               Description
+++-===========================================-==========================-==========================-============================================================================================
ii  linux-headers-generic                       3.16.0.28.29               amd64                      Generic Linux kernel headers
```

However, I do not have this kernel on disk:

```
# ls -l /boot
total 40215
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1163858 aug 15 04:56 abi-3.13.0-35-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   165652 aug 15 04:56 config-3.13.0-35-generic
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root     1024 nov 13 20:24 extlinux
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root     1024 dec 22 18:43 grub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 30105783 jan  2 09:27 initrd.img-3.13.0-35-generic
drwx------ 2 root root    12288 aug 22 21:20 lost+found
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   176500 mrt 12  2014 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   178176 mrt 12  2014 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   178680 mrt 12  2014 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw------- 1 root root  3386444 aug 15 04:56 System.map-3.13.0-35-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  5806368 aug 15 04:56 vmlinuz-3.13.0-35-generic
```

Nor do I have it running:

```
# uname -r
3.13.0-35-generic
```

When I install the package, it tells me I already have it:

```
# apt-get install linux-headers-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-generic is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Same result when I specifically ask for the version:

```
# apt-get install linux-headers-3.16.0-28-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-3.16.0-28-generic is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Just to be sure, checking to see if the kernel is on disk now, but it isn't:

```
# ls -l /boot
total 40215
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1163858 aug 15 04:56 abi-3.13.0-35-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   165652 aug 15 04:56 config-3.13.0-35-generic
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root     1024 nov 13 20:24 extlinux
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root     1024 dec 22 18:43 grub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 30105783 jan  2 09:27 initrd.img-3.13.0-35-generic
drwx------ 2 root root    12288 aug 22 21:20 lost+found
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   176500 mrt 12  2014 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   178176 mrt 12  2014 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   178680 mrt 12  2014 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw------- 1 root root  3386444 aug 15 04:56 System.map-3.13.0-35-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  5806368 aug 15 04:56 vmlinuz-3.13.0-35-generic
```

Rebooting doesn't help. I'm confused.